# Highlight the block only when it starts to appear in the visibility zone

Tags: javascript

I have my own time, but it works with errors. Maybe there is someone in the collection?

That's my time. Here he when appears in the field of visibility of 20% of the screen begins to be painted

```
let scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

if ( ( scrollY + document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.8
        > el.offsetTop &&
        scrollY < el.offsetTop ) ||
        scrollY < el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight &&
        scrollY > el.offsetTop
    ) {
          el.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
      }
```

My full code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJQKRw

Works only for the second section. And for the blocks inside the first section it works with errors. The script does not work the same time

Comment: Isn't this a CSS issue?

Comment: @JarekKulikowski did not understand you. How to do this through css?

Comment: If you changes are working and only apply to 20% of the screen then maybe el is defined to cover only 20% of the screen. I don't know your full code to answer this question completely.

Comment: @JarekKulikowski Briefly, the block should be painted once as soon as it appears in the visibility zone. Regardless of whether I scroll up or down

Comment: I think I would have to see more of your code before I could reply with a useful comment.  Specifically HTML and how you define `el`.

Comment: @JarekKulikowski full code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJQKRw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150507/discussion-between-nikolay-and-jarek-kulikowski).